# Load clicked URLs from AJAX loaded page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have the following code which fetches content from another page using AJAX:

```html
<div id="content">
</div>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/Home/", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

It works! Sadly, when you click on an URL from that page, all of the already loaded code disapears. :(

So my question is:
How can I make the clicked URLs load inside my DIV (content)?

Cheers.

Comment: um, more javascript and ajax?

Comment: To be honest im unshure of what I should add to this script to make it work like I want...

Comment: And I do not have time to write code for you. Basically you have to find the links, and hijack them....

Comment: I searched this website and other forums for about an hour now.. :P If by any chance, you know a link that could help me, please tell me.